# Javascript: Add Key to an Multiple Object of Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this object that log out as in:

```
{0: "16407", 1: "16309", 2: "16308", 3: "16307", 4: "16306", 5: "16305", 6: "16303", 7: "16302", 8: "16301", 9: "16300", 10: "16299", 11: "16298", 12: "16297", 13: "16296", 14: "16294", 15: "16293", 16: "16292", 17: "16290", 18: "16285", 19: "16277"}
```

How can I restructure this to log out as follows:

```
{"name": "16407" }, {"name": "16309"}, {"name": "16308"}....
```

Comment: `console.log(Object.values(o).map(v => \`{"name": "${v}" }\`).join(", "));` but i think the question went right over my head.

Comment: What do you mean with *"log out"*. Are you only interested in an output string, not an object structure?

Comment: Thanks @tirincot ! I mean log out to output but I would eventually wanna use it so maybe store it in a variable...

Comment: `Object.values(o).map(v => ({name: v}))`

Comment: So, is the input a single object, and the result an array of objects? It would be nice if you would present the expected result as a JavaScript object/array literal. Like the above suggestions could work, or `Object.values(o).map(name => ({name}))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could move the values into an array and map objects.

```js
var object = { 0: "16407", 1: "16309", 2: "16308", 3: "16307", 4: "16306", 5: "16305", 6: "16303", 7: "16302", 8: "16301", 9: "16300", 10: "16299", 11: "16298", 12: "16297", 13: "16296", 14: "16294", 15: "16293", 16: "16292", 17: "16290", 18: "16285", 19: "16277" },
    result = Object.assign([], object).map(name => ({ name }));

console.log(result);
```